# Order clause with explicit order

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy, sql-order-by

I have a row with three possible results

```
no 
neutral
yes
```

I want to preserve this order. `Desc` or `ASC` will not match. So, there is any way to specify what is the order expected?

Not sure if is relevant, but I am using sql alchemy.

```
.order_by(Survey.rating).all()
```

Answer (score 2):

Arrays can be convenient for this type of logic in Postgres.  One method  is:

```
array_position(array['no', 'neutral', 'yes'], colname)
```

This is convenient because it is easy to expand to more values.

Comment: any idea how to implement that in sqlalchemy API?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a case expression to control the ordering when there's no natural sequence to do it.

```
order by case col1 when 'no' then 1 when 'neutral' then 2 else 3 end
```

Comment: how this can be translated to sqlalchemy api?

Answer (score 1):

As of today, I made [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59160222/1331394) working fine:

```
from sqlalchemy import func
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import array
...
    select_query.order_by(
        func.array_position(
            array((first_id, second_id)),
            self.table.c.id,
        )
    )
```

Pay an attention, that into the array function with ids you should pass tuple, not a list (at least I've got error with `array([first_id, second_id])`).

Answer (score 0):

For sqlalchemy API we can use 'func'

```
from sqlalchemy import func

.order_by(func.array_position(array['no', 'neutral', 'yes'], colname) )
```

But also we should check cast type for `colname`, b/c we need to indicate the datatype of an element explicitly (sqlalchemy has a function `cast` for this).

Then indicating the type, we will have the following:

```
from sqlalchemy import cast, Text

.order_by(func.array_position(array['no', 'neutral', 'yes'], cast(table.c.colname, Text)) )
```